# Primary key design - autoincrement vs composite vs artificial key for time-series data

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

I have a non-relational table that records visits per area across time (months):

| area_id | period | visitors | visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 91387821 | 2022-04 | 452 | 664 |
| 91387821 | 2022-05 | 516 | 704 |
| 105252924 | 2022-04 | 8834 | 20445 |

etc.

I need to load this data into a Postgres DB, and generate a primary key for each tuple.

My options for the primary key are:

1. Use auto-increment key.
2. Use a composite key combining `area_id` and `period`.
3. Generate a unique key from `area_id` and `period` e.g. 20220491387821 or 91387821202204 for the first record.

Which option will provide the best performance for running summaries across periods per area id? The table is going to have hundreds of millions of records, corresponding to millions of unique `area_id`s.

Comment: I would prefer 2 or maybe 1. Option 3 is pretty much the same as 2. but makes things unnecessary complicated and has no advantage over 2.

Comment: does the combination of an integer and date have any performance implications?

Comment: If you know that the combination is guaranteed to be unique, and you never want to update those columns, go with 2.